# What is wrong with using DateTime.Now. as main part of Unique ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, security, language-agnostic

I used to use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` to generate string-based Order ID's, but, there were 4 instances where `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@$%^*()_-` would generate an already-existing Order ID.

And it got me thinking...

Why can't we just use something like:

```
<html>
...
<p>@GenerateOrderId()</p>
...
</html>
```

and:

```
public string GenerateOrderId()
{
   return "OID" + 
      DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month +
      DateTime.Now.Day + 
      DateTime.Now.Hour + 
      DateTime.Now.Minute + 
      DateTime.Now.Second + 
      DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
}
```

I've been told that it's a bad idea, but without any explanation, or reason, it's still stuck in my head.
... The reason I'd like to use this, is because it will *always* be unique.

Comment: Why are you sure it will always be unique?

Comment: Why not use a GUID?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Computers work at nanosecond speeds. You would be guaranteed to generate a duplicate order ID almost immediately.

Your best bet would be to use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) *<sup>[[MSDN-C#]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)</sup>*  *<sup>[[MSDN-SQL]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)</sup>* (a.k.a. `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in the SQL world).

Comment: Additionally, DateTime.Now is generally not sampled at real-time.  From MSDN, _"The resolution of this property depends on the system timer."_

Comment: How about `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)*Date.now();`?

Answer (score 7):

It won't *always* be unique.

If the same process is carried out during the same millisecond, then it will be identical.

As [@Bill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849039/what-is-wrong-with-using-datetime-now-as-main-part-of-order-id/11849071#comment15758342_11849039) has stated, you should use a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) for a unique string.

Answer (score 6):

Never call the `Now` getter that many times. "Now" may change while you're adding the strings. You **could** say `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")` or similar, but it's much better to use `Guid.NewGuid()` for this.

Comment: To elaborate, as an example, suppose it's 15:59 when you evaluate `DateTime.Now.Hour`, but when you evaluate `DateTime.Now.Minute` time has changed to 16:00. Then the corresponding part of your string will read `1500` which is confusing as it's approximately one hour off the true time your order ID was generated.

Comment: And if that happens, it could possible be a dupe, if there was already an order id generated at 1500.. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @EvilCokeMachine Exactly. Therefore, if you insist to use `DateTime.Now`, make sure you call it only once. You may save the value to a local variable and read that variable several times.

Comment: I like using NewGUID, though it really is a pain for many customers who have to reference it over the phone. And from the looks of it, on MSDN, you can't actually create a custom-formatted GUID

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a globally unique identifier and aren't bothered about the format, why don't you just use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx

```
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine(g);
    }
}
```

[It even has a type in T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) (which you may well be using given that you're using ASP.NET)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend letting your database handle that responsibility, but if you must do it in code, then use GUID. GUID has a low probability of being duplicated.

```
  public string GenerateOrderId()
  {
    return System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to beat a dead horse, but your usage of `DateTime.Now` is of more concern than what you're trying to do. You can rewrite your method and achieve the same goal much more succinctly:

```
public string GenerateOrderID()
{
  return "OID" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
}
```

I would still recommend using a `Guid` over this approach. However, 99% of the time, the `Ticks` property is going to give you a different number each time it's called.

Comment: The system timers resolution is still too low, to use it as a unique value. MSDN states an approximate resolution of ~10ms for ≥ NT 3.5 (which is an eternity for a computer). The GUID on the other hand is designed for exactly the problem at hand.

Comment: @ollb I agree which is why I stated that I recommend `Guid` over this approach. My answer simply suggests that if you're set on using `DateTime.Now` then you should only call it once.