# Can using Ticks of DateTime.Now can generate duplicates unique identifiers?

Tags: c#, performance, datetime, for-loop, uniqueidentifier

Is there a possibility for this code to generate the same identity,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        string TransID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    }
```

What are the considerations that make this happen?

Comment: if i understand your question correctly. can you check this question? They seem similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849039/what-is-wrong-with-using-datetime-now-as-main-part-of-unique-id
`Guid.NewGuid()` is a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, this code can generate the same identifier.**

Regardless of the tick precision, it can do so if the system date is changed in Windows and/or the Bios.

*And also if it is run by computers in different time zones or if you travel.*

**The latter case implies that you should absolutely not use such a code even in local and not-connected applications.**

If you need ID for a personnal and local application, and you never travel, this code does what you want, but it is not recommended to use such bad pattern.

As everyone says, without being wrong, you should use `Guid.New()` which is actually the safest standard, or an int or a long auto-increment (for local or managed by a server) for a better performance in some cases.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

[How expensive is a GUID cast and comparison vs a string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120196/how-expensive-is-a-guid-cast-and-comparison-vs-a-string-comparison)

Comment: I did not know these aspects, thank you for this good answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's define what is a tick. A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second.

> 1 second = 10 million ticks

Basically, if you don't generate two ID's at the same time, you're OK.

Also, I would suggest you to watch [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-5.0) as an alternative. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

this piece of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    string TransID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
}
```

won't generate unique TransIDs on a computer which performs more than 10 million for loops per second.

Comment: At 4 GHz on a modern processor, how many instructions could be run in the time of a single tick?

Comment: One cycle per second is known as 1 hertz. This means that a CPU with a clock speed of 4 gigahertz (GHz) can carry out 4 thousand million (or 4 billion) cycles per second

Comment: Oh, I added my comment before your edit. It was intended to point out that "Basically, if you don't generate two ID's at the same time, you're OK." doesn't help with a modern processor.

Comment: My wooden PC generated 20 unique ID's ;)) That's why at first I forgot about that aspect