# How to create a primary key where order of similar elements is ignored

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm creating my first SQLite database in a C# program. The program is related to poker/playing cards. I have a table called Flop defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Flop 
(
     id SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
     card1 TINYINT NOT NULL,
     card2 TINYINT NOT NULL,
     card3 TINYINT NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT Flop_pk PRIMARY KEY (card1, card2, card3)
);
```

`Flop` contains the id of 3 playing cards from a 52 card deck and I want to avoid duplicate Flop rows where the 3 cards match but are in a different order. If my card ids are 1,2,3 I wish to prevent adding an entry for a Flop of 2,3,1 or 1,3,2 etc. How do I set up my key constraints so that the card order is ignored?

Also, how can I select a flop given that my 3 cards passed into the `SELECT` statement may be in any order? I assume there must be a more simple way than checking all 6 combos like:

```
SELECT id FROM Flop WHERE (card1 = 1 AND card2 = 2 AND card3 = 3) 
                       OR (card1 = 3 AND card2 = 1 AND card3 = 2) 
                       OR (card1 = 2 AND card2 = 3 AND card3 = 1) 
                       OR (card1 = 1 AND card2 = 3 AND card3 = 2)
                       OR (card1 = 2 AND card2 = 1 AND card3 = 3)
                       OR (card1 = 3 AND card2 = 2 AND card3 = 1);
```

Comment: The primary key is id, not that triplet... else useless and duplicates: [How do you like your primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404040/) • [Generate unique Integers based on GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920696/) • [Can using Ticks of DateTime.Now can generate duplicates unique identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550289/) • [Guid vs INT - Which is better as a primary key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264/guid-vs-int-which-is-better-as-a-primary-key) • [Universally unique ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: Ah, so if I implement a get hashcode method for Flops I could use that code as both an ID and a way to retrieve entries. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: My actual DB entries will be in the form: KEY:Flop,Hand1,Hand2 VALUES: Hand1Wins, Draws. I'm using the values to calculate equity having presolved data for all possible subsequent cards. I tried calculating in realtime but it took around 20secs which is far too slow for me. So I'm working on finding an efficient way to store and retrieve the data.

Comment: On a given flop there are 990 possible outcomes with 2 cards still to be dealt. I've calculated the possible outcomes to determine the equity of 1 hand vs another on a given flop. In my program I calculate the equity of a range of hands vs another range of hands so there can be a large number of combinations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this by implementing a GetHashCode method in my C# code that sorts the cards prior to calculating a hashcode for the Flop object. This resulted in a consistent code being generated irrespective of the order of cards input to the method and also gave me a fast way to retrieve a row from the database using the ID as primary key

Answer (score 0):

If your version of SQLite is 3.31.0+ you can add to the table a [generated column](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html) which will be a string that consists of the values of the 3 columns in ascending order with a `,` as separator.
So, if the values of the columns are `5`, `7` and `3` the value of the generated column will be `'3,5,7'`.
This way you can define a `UNIQUE` constraint on this generated column.

The `CREATE` statement of the table should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Flop (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
     card1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
     card2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
     card3 INTEGER NOT NULL,
     cards AS (
       MIN(card1, card2, card3) || ',' ||
       (card1 + card2 + card3 - MIN(card1, card2, card3) - MAX(card1, card2, card3)) || ',' ||
       MAX(card1, card2, card3)
     ) UNIQUE,
     CHECK(card1 <> card2 AND card1 <> card3 AND card2 <> card3)
);
```

Note that I have defined the column `id` to be the primary key, although you don't actually need it, since every SQLite table has the column [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) to serve the same purpose.

I added a constraint that I think you need, that not any 2 of the 3 values are equal.

Also, there is no `TINYINT` data type in SQLite (although you can use it and SQLite will not complain), so I changed them all to `INTEGER` (you can find more in [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).

Finally, if you want to query the table for 3 specific values, if you want to use the generated column you must provide the 3 values in a string in ascending order as a comma separated list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Flop 
WHERE cards = '3,5,7';
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Flop 
WHERE card1 IN (3,5,7) AND card2 IN (3,5,7) AND card3 IN (3,5,7);
```

The order of the values in the `IN` list is not important.

Answer (score 0):

**The best way to enforce this is to enforce that all `card`s be in ascending order**

```sql
CHECK (card1 < card2 AND card2 < card3)
```

Then all you need to do when selecting is to select the cards in ascending order.

I would recommend at this point to remove the primary key, and make a compound primary key instead `(card1, card2, card3)`